# Unity prefab clone is not visible in runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two prefabs which have sprite renderer,collider,rigidbody2D.
I instantiate 20 of their clone separately and transform in runtime. The clone are created in object panel still it in active state but not visible in both game and scene I need help.am a begginer

Comment: No one can answer this question. Please provide some code and if it's possible a screenshot of your Gameobjects hierarchy.

Comment: Some code and picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this

1. **Object out of view**:Your game object could be placed outside the view frustrum(not in view of the camera)
2. **game Object inactive**:May be some of the attributes are inactive thus the visual aspect of it is not visible try dragging the prefab on the screen outside debug mode
3. **Out of canvas**:May be you have a UI element outside the canvas

there may be soo many reasons for it if you could put some screenshots or something to help us with your problem may be we can pin point it